# how does this Regular Expression extract the company name?

Tags: .net, regex

Could you expand on why the output of `Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);` would be `Contoso, Inc`?
And could you also elaborate on the matching steps of this example? Thanks.

PS: I'm not familiar with the concept of groups

```
string input = "Company Name: Contoso, Inc."; 
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"Company Name: (.*$)"); 
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not familar with the concept of groups

A group is a part of the regular expression that is saved while doing the matching. To declare a group in your regular expression, you put a part of the expression between parentheses. That part is then saved inside a group.

Groups are numbered (although they can also be given explicit names), from left to right, from the outside to the inside. The “zero-th” group is the whole match.

In your case, you print the first group, which is just the last part of the string, i.e. everything behind “`Company Name:`” up until the end of the line.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the matching steps of this example? Thanks.

Comment: We see "Company Name: ", then we capture all other symbols into the group number 1, because ".*$" matches them all.

Answer (score 1):

The docs contain all the information about groups, but I think that each time you use parentheses in the pattern, you create a matching group. Groups[0] is the text matched by the pattern, and Groups[i] (where i> 0) represent the nth matched pattern in parentheses.
You could also name groups.

Answer (score 1):

Groups are denoted by a set of parenthesis. Basically your regex is saying: In order to match, any incoming string will have to start with `Company Name:` and the rest of the string can be any characters, the `.*`, including the end of the string, `$`. Since `.*$` is in parenthesis, you have said that you want to group that match. Remember that you could have more groups. The entire input string is always `Groups[0]` (if it matches that is), which is why your expression `(.*$)` is in `Groups[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm studying Regular Expressions right now, so this is some good practice for me :)

The regular expression you use is **"Company Name: (.*$)"** and you use the RegExOptions.SingleLine to match your string (this is the default option).

*"Company Name: "* will be matched starting from anywhere in the string (if you would have used **"^Company Name: "** you would have said that **"Company Name: "** has to be the first part of the string. ( ^ = beginnig of the string)

`(.*$)`  this is a unnamed group.

Inside this group you are matching for `".*$"` , that translates into: any character `"."`, taken 0 or more times `"*"`, until the end of the string `"$"`

Clear? :)

Comment: `(?.*$)` is a not valid expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interesting in learning the ins and outs of Regular Expressions (along with how the different implementations vary based on language and platform), then I definitely recommend [Mastering Regular Expressions from O'Reilly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124).